# If-else and default condition in groovy script

Tags: if-statement, groovy

Is there any way to add default condition into if else loop. If X is true then operation1 executes else operation2. If X is null then default operation gets executed.

```
if (x)
{ operation1 }
else
{ operation2 }
default
{default operation}
```

Comment: `if(x) {...} else if (x!=null) {...} else {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No default null-condition is provided in Java/Groovy as a `null` is not treated as default case.

You have to check against the `null` yourself:

```
if (null)
{ operationNull }
else if (x)
{ operation1 }
else
{ operation2 }
```